# c# Httprequestmessage serialization/deserialization without loosing scheme

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I'm trying to serialize a C# HttpRequestMessage by using standard .NET serializers but the serialization disregards scheme, turning https requests into http requests.

This is basically what I'm trying to do (a simplified version of https://gist.github.com/aliostad/3202814) with a simple assertion at the end.

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://some.server/api/foo");

var stream = new MemoryStream();
var httpMessageContent = new HttpMessageContent(requestMessage);
var buffer = httpMessageContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
stream.Position = 0;

var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(memoryStream.ToArray());
request.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/http;msgtype=request");

var result = await request.Content.ReadAsHttpRequestMessageAsync();

Debug.Assert("https" == result.RequestUri.Scheme);
```

I could solve the problem by adding state to my other objects, which specifies schema but I rather not.

Also, `request.Content.ReadAsHttpRequestMessageAsync()` does accept schema as a parameter but at deserialization I don't know the schema, it could be a http request or a https request.

I've looked at the following thread but it's the same problem there, scheme is lost upon serialization/deserialization. ([Serialize and deserialize HttpRequestMessage objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26611339/serialize-and-deserialize-httprequestmessage-objects))

Does anyone have a fix for this issue or an entirely different approach?

Comment: You never even set a `RequestUri` on `request`. I would expect the assert to throw a `NullReferenceException`. Is the scheme really `http`?

Comment: @Crowcoder No, it's initialized and will return http.

Comment: I confused `request` with `result`. What is the value of its `RequestUri` ?